# Unable to install virtualenv on Mac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.5

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I am running Mac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.5. I tried to install virtualenv and got message saying I need to upgrade pip to a later version

```
AKALBAG-M-82RZ:Python amkalbag$ pip install --user virtualenv
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting virtualenv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

So I tired upgrading pip:

```
AKALBAG-M-82RZ:~ amkalbag$ pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I also tried using sudo, but that did not help either.

```
AKALBAG-M-82RZ:~ amkalbag$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
Password:
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I keep getting message "Requirement already up-to-date".

How can I upgrade to pip version 10.0.1 so I may then install virtualenv?

Comment: First, are you trying to install this for Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7.10, or for a different Python (2.7 or otherwise) that you installed separately? Also, how did you install `pip` in the first place? (Apple's Python doesn't come with `pip`, but Homebrew Python does, and python.org does since Python 2.7.9+ and 3.4+, so you may not have installed it.) Finally, are you sure you _want_ to install this for whatever old version of Python you're using, instead of first upgrading to 3.7.0 or 2.7.15 and then just using the `pip` that it comes with?

Comment: Second: the error isn't telling you that you need to upgrade `pip` to a later version. There's a *recommendation* that "you should consider upgrading", then there's a completely separate error about not being able to find a distribution for `virtualenv`. This _could_ be because you have a truly ancient `pip`, but I don't think 6.1.1 is ancient enough for that to be the case. So, you may well be trying to fix an irrelevant problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response @abarnert!  I have Python 2.7.10.  I don't remember whether it was pre-installed or whether I installed it some time ago.  pip was already installed, so I guess it came with Python.

As for your second point, when I was researching the problem with installing virtualenv, I came across some posts that said the problem is relate to TLS and said that pip needs to be upgraded to fix it.  Hence, I was trying to upgrade pip.

Comment: There is a problem with TLS with pip 9, but I think pip 6 is actually old enough that it doesn't come up. And you aren't seeing the error message that goes with that error. Anyway, here's an easy way to check whether you're using Apple's pre-installed Python: from you Terminal, type `which python`. If it's `/usr/bin/python`, that's Apple's. And the first question is: do you actually want to stick with Apple's Python? They preinstall a bunch of stuff that's useful, but also old, and do it in a way that makes it hard to update.

Comment: Also, do you actually need Python 2 instead of 3? Python 2.7 is 9 years old, and will be going permanently out of support in a year and a half, and there are already many packages that don't support it (or only support it with old versions that get nothing more than critical security bug fixes).

Comment: @abarnert thanks again!
I did `which python` and it shows the following:
`
AKALBAG-M-82RZ:AWS Projects amkalbag$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
`

Comment: I also have Python 3 on my Mac.  I tried using pip from Python 3 by using the pip3 command as follows:
`
AKALBAG-M-82RZ:AWS Projects amkalbag$ pip3 install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/amkalbag/.pip/pip.log
`
However, I still get errors.

Comment: OK, your pip3 is trying to use the old (2016-era) PyPI URL. Can you try `pip3 install --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple --upgrade pip setuptools`? If that works, hopefully it'll also update the default index, so you can just `pip3 install virtualenv`. (The same thing might also work for your Python 2.7 `pip`, but I suspect that, if it does, you're going to run into the TLS problem… so at least try the `pip3` one first.)

Comment: If that doesn't work, the next step is to reinstall pip. Do `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`, then `python3 ./get-pip.py`, then, assuming that works, `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools` just to be safe, and `pip3 install virtualenv`. (Again, the same thing might work for 2.7, but it might not—in this case because of weird interactions with Apple's `Extras` packages—so again, try 3.x first.)

Comment: @abarnert before you responded with your comments, I had found another post and tried reinstalling pip.  I was still having problems and figured I'd just start with a clean slate.  I got rid of both my 2.7 (not the original installed by Apple, but the one I had installed some time ago) and 3.4 Python installations and plan to re-install just 3.4.  I will need to see if the issues with pip still persists.  Will keep you posted. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: @abarnert. After doing a fresh install of Python 3.7 using the installer from Python.org, my environment now works!  This install comes with a private copy of OpneSSL 1.1.0 so my pip issues with certificates are resolved.  It also has the venv module for creating virtual environments so I did not need to install virtualenv.  Thank you so much for answering all my questions.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it all worked out. It's worth noting that `venv` isn't 100% equivalent to `virtualenv`, so there are some people who prefer to install it anyway—but if you don't need it, you don't need it, and hopefully it'll install now if you do need it.